# Anonymous extended class typedef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-generics, anonymous-types

I got this working function which I would like to have a better typedef for than `any` as action and return type. `action` should be a class and the return type should be class which extends `action`.

```js
function createAction(state: string, action: any): any {
  return class extends action {
    public static readonly type = `[${state}] ${action.name}`;
    constructor(...args: any) {
      super(...args);
    }
  };
}
```

I tried using Angulars `Type<T>` which didn't work out.

If the only option to make this work would be to have an `Interface` on my `action` class and using that `Interface` for typedef it would be fine as well, as long as the `Interface` would be somewhat generic.

I imagine something along the lines of this as a solution, but i can't quite get it to work:

```js
function createAction<T>(state: string, action: Type<T>): Type<X extends T> {
```

Comment: I can look at this more closely later, but if you read the typescript docs on mixins I bet you can figure it out, as that’s very close to what you are doing here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html

Comment: Also you don’t need to include the constructor/super call at all of you aren’t adding anything to the constructor.

Comment: Good spot @LindaPaiste I will remove that